# Qt IDE run error: cannot open .so file but running from terminal it is fine

Tags: qt, dll, cuda

I wrote a simple code to test CUDA with Qt on Linux Ubuntu.

While running app within Qt IDE I get the following error:
[image]

However while running app from command line I don't get any erorr and all computation done by CUDA are correct.

Also while running CUDA samples from command line, everything is okay.

Also all paths in Qt .pro file are set correctly

So the question is why Qt IDE prompts me with above error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem fixed.

Turns out that LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not do its job. 
What I did instead was:

1. add this

> /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64

to

> /etc/ld/so/conf

file

2. Run

> sudo ldconfig

I hope it will help somone

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is an environment variable that guides the runtime linker behavior.  Apparently Qt IDE doesn't pick up that environment when it runs.  `ldconfig` actually *modifies* the behavior of the runtime linker for all future invocations of it, regardless of when/where or from which user they originate.

Comment: It would be good if you could accept this answer, so that the question falls off the unanswered question list for the CUDA tag